# Sorting images by file number with PHP

Tags: php, image, sorting

Here's a simplified version of the code I am currently using.

```
$files = glob('*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$counter = 1;
echo '<div id="images">';
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($counter % $IMGS_PER_ROW == 1)
        echo '<div>';
    echo '<img src="' . $file . '"/>';
    if ($counter % $IMGS_PER_ROW == 0)
    echo '</div>';
    $counter++; 
}
echo '</div>';
```

What this does, is searches through a directory, and for each image that it finds, it prints to the screen inline, with a maximum of `$IMGS_PER_ROW` images per line.

The problem with this, is that lets say we have 15 images, with their titles respective to the number of the image (i.e. `0.jpg`, `1.jpg`, ... `14.jpg`), they will be printed in order based on their name as String. (i.e. `0.jpg`, `1.jpg`, `10.jpg`, `11.jpg`, `12.jpg`, `13.jpg`, `14.jpg`, `2.jpg`, ...).

Obviously, I want them in numerical order, so a sorting algorithm is inevitable (I think). I'm not too strong at php, and was wondering if there was a simple O(n^2) way of sorting this array of file locations by numerical order, rather than by string comparison.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's no O(n) way of sorting, sorting is at least O(n * log(n)). Also, afaik `glob` does not sort, it just takes the files the order they are stored in the file system.

Comment: I meant O(n^2), wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`natcasesort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) or [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) before iterating:

```
$files = glob('*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
natcasesort($files);
foreach($files as $file) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Well, that was easier than expected, thanks. Didn't know it was called 'natural ordering', but that makes sense...

Comment: An excellent post on the same topic - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
   $a = array("0.jpg", "1.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg", "13.jpg", "14.jpg", "2.jpg");
   natcasesort ($a);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort the array numerically after globbing:

```
$files = glob(…);
sort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach(…) {
  …;
}
```